# How to upload array of image links to Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I just completed a blog app that allows a user to upload a single image as a post. I am using Firestore to save the image link from Cloud Storage

```
final StorageReference postPath.putFile(mainImageURI).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                      if (task.isSuccessful()){
                          downloadUri = 
        task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
       Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("image_url", downloadUri);
                        {
```

However, i now intend to allow users upload multiple images for each post. Uploading the images to Cloud Storage is no problem for me. But how can i save an array of image links for one document child in Cloud Storage. I have not been able to figure this out. Please help.

Comment: did you solve your problem

Comment: i am facing the same problem right now, can you post your answer please so that all of us see it and upvoting

Comment: check it out bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private ArrayList<String> image_urls;

.....

 image_urls = new ArrayList<>();
//add your images strings to the array list

// send to firestore with map function
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("image_urls", image_urls);
 firebaseFirestore.collection("Posts").add(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Firestore has an array type for fields.  Simply populate an ArrayList with the strings of all the URLs you want to write, and make that the value of a field in the document where you want to store it.

Answer (score 0):

On the storage side, I don't think there are "sub-levels" like folders or similars, but on Firestore, you can do as the other answer tells you, or add the links as a collection to any document. Basically create a dictionary with them and add them just like that.